# Batch file to copy the file from a specific folder and not the sub folders to the target folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried to execute the below script, which copies the latest file from one folder to another folder. But I tested the below script in different scenario, in which it even copies the file CC*.txt if it exists in sub folders apart from C:\Source.
But I wanted to copy the latest file from only the source directory (C:\Source) mentioned in the script below, but if the same new file exists in any of the folders/sub-folders should NOT be taken to consideration, kindly suggest.

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR "C:\Source\cc*.txt" /B /A:-D /T:W /O:D /S') DO SET "LATEST=%%~I"
COPY "%LATEST%" "C:\Destination"
```

PS: Mostly because of `/S`, but I am not sure what option need to use to pick the file only from the specified directory `C:\Source`, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove the `/S` option (which tells `dir` to process sub-directories also):

```
FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR "C:\Source\cc*.txt" /B /A:-D /T:W /O:D') DO SET "LATEST=%%~I"
COPY "C:\Source\%LATEST%" "C:\Destination"
```

Since `dir /B` without the `/S` switch returns the pure file names only, you need to include the source location in the copy source once again for the script to work from any working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b /s /O:D "C:\Source\cc*.txt"') do set "latest=%%A"
copy "%latest%" "C:\Destination"`

Answer (score 0):

`FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR cc*.txt /B /O:-D') DO COPY %%I "C:\Destination" & EXIT`
Super easy.

`FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "cc*.txt" /B /O:D') DO COPY %%I "C:\Destination"`

Both should do